# MediaWiki: Database schema error when searching

Tags: mediawiki

I installed MediaWiki on my Mac with MAMP (PHP7.2.10 and MySQL 5.7.23 InnoDB). No error occured and everything except the search works. It shows the following error instead of a result:

```
[c1af9047a60a292a781befdd] /mediawiki/index.php?search=test&title=Spezial%3ASuche&go=Seite Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError from line 1457 of /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: A database query error has occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema updater after upgrading?
Query: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'ft\_min\_word\_len'
Function: SearchMySQL::minSearchLength
Error: 1682 Native table 'performance_schema'.'global_variables' has the wrong structure (localhost)

Backtrace:

#0 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1427): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->makeQueryException(string, integer, string, string)
#1 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1200): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError(string, integer, string, string, boolean)
#2 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php(446): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query(string, string)
#3 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php(402): SearchMySQL->minSearchLength()
#4 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php(104): SearchMySQL->normalizeText(string)
#5 /Users/bxxx/www/mediawiki/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php(299): SearchMySQL->parseQuery(string, boolean)
#6 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php(273): SearchMySQL->queryMain(array, string, boolean)
#7 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php(188): SearchMySQL->getQuery(string, boolean)
#8 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php(178): SearchMySQL->searchInternal(string, boolean)
#9 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/specials/SpecialSearch.php(318): SearchMySQL->searchTitle(string)
#10 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/specials/SpecialSearch.php(185): SpecialSearch->showResults(string)
#11 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(522): SpecialSearch->execute(NULL)
#12 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(568): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#13 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(288): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#14 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(861): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#15 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(524): MediaWiki->main()
#16 /Users/xxx/www/mediawiki/index.php(42): MediaWiki->run()
#17 {main}
```

A first attempt was to start the web updater, but /mwconfig/ only allows the download of the LocalSettings.php. No way to actually start it.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think its a generell Problem with the MySQL installation. Reinstalling the server fixed it.

Comment: Indeed, `performance_schema` is used by MySQL internally. Any problems with that are going to be unrelated to MediaWiki.